# Can I print custom receipt on receipt printer?

Tags: php, printing

Currently I need to build a small site for a shop and they need to print receipt. However, this is the first time I touch these receipt printer, so I am not too sure will the php code for normal printer work on this. Did anyone use these receipt printer before?

The receipt printer is connected to a laptop and the web application (php) will be use on this laptop.

receipt printer model: Epson m129c

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with receipt printers before, but not written any PHP code etc for it. I believe they work as normal printers.

EDIT:
Uhm, but is the PHP code running on the laptop, or is the laptop just visiting some website that runs the code, because the latter doesn't work. PHP is server side scripting.

Comment: nope, the laptop is just visiting that web application and printing out the result. I assume it will work the same with the php code I had. Will give a try next week when I do the pre-install (testing).